# Moving only Elementary Hera OS from a 1Tb HDD to a 120Gb SSD

Tags: release-hera, ssd, hdd

I have a Dell Inspiration 15 5555 with Elementary OS Hera which has a base 1Tb HDD, but I wanted upgrade it and recently install a 120Gb SSD using a caddy replacing my DVD/optical drive. Now I want to move my only the OS from the HDD to the SSD but keeping my Documents on the HDD. How can I do it? All the information I can find on the web migrates all the data and my documents are much bigger than 120Gb plus those doesn't need so much read/write speed as the one the SSD offers.
Already format the SSD using ext4 but I can't find how to move **only** the OS. If it's need I still have the OS bootable with Hera.
Been using Elementary OS for 2 years so theoretically I should understand it but to be honest most of the time I have no idea what is going on so please help me.

Comment: You should be able to follow most "migrate to smaller disk" guides, but will need to omit moving the `/home` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to move your documents off to another storage medium temporarily (backup drive or thumb drive), wipe them off your HDD then copy the contents of your now much-smaller HDD  to your new SSD then copy your documents back over to your HDD?

Comment: Would be kind of hard because I only have 1 USB with not enough space... but yes, indeed I could backup everything, format both disks and then boot, this time with the SSD but there must be a way to do it without reinstalling everything, right? After all it is already installed

Answer (score 0):

So do you mean that you want upgrading to an SSD, but you insist on keeping your current OS? I think you can try to clone your HDD to SSD. maybe this [article](https://itsfoss.com/upgrading-solid-state-drive-linux/) is quite helpful